# Can't place context-controlled block below user picture on user profile page

Tags: 7, views, users

I have a views block of user content that I want to display on the user profile page below a custom generated block of user information created in code via a theme function (using the $build['user_picture'] element in hook_entity_view_alter().  If I place the block into the appropriate region using the blocks admin page and configure the block to only appear at user/*, it works fine. However, if I place the block using Context module with the User Profile condition, it places the block above all other content, and there seems to be nothing I can do to drop the block below the user_picture element.  The weight for the user picture element is set to -10 by default, but even if I make it lower, nothing changes is.

Is there a way to control the placement of the block via Context so it is below the user_picture element? I can see no way via the UI - either for Context or user profile configuration - or code. Do I have to override user-profile.tpl.php and manually split everything out? I need to use Context to be able to control which user profiles the block is on, so if I can't re-order, then I have to find another mechanism (probably Panels) to control this placement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the general rule (at least for me) that posting a question in a public forum somehow helps me find the answer, I figured this out as soon as I posted this. All I had to do was click on the "Show row weights" link, alter the weight, and that put it right where I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

> The weight for the user picture element is set to -10 by default, but
>   even if I make it lower, nothing changes is.

The default weight for system content is 0, so display below that you would want a weight of 1 or more for your block in Context > Reaction > Block (if I'm understanding your issue correctly).